# Fullwidth Embeded Youtube Video

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to embed my youtube video with full screen.
but there's a problem: the video has BLACK SIDES on right and left.

here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/vXy1G2JeJo0?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&allowfullscreen=true&wmode=transparent&iv_load_policy=3&html5=1

there's a right and left bands on screen.

I just want to make it like here: http://acwistanbul.com/

please, just help me.
i couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this resource may help you http://embedresponsively.com

Explanation

> On said resource enter your youtube video link and click embed. This
>   will generate code for a fullscreen'd responsive embedded youtube
>   video.